# React Hooks useEffect called again on route change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Entire code is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-sea-krlff

Main issue is that useEffect called again on route change.

1. Go to Employee page from Hooks main via: props.history.push('/employee');
2. Come back to HooksMain page from Employee page via: props.history.push('/');
3. This triggers useEffect again and another service call though it is dependant on parameter "test".

Details Below:

1st functional component:

```
import React, {
  useState,
} from 'react';

function HooksMain(props) {
  const [test, setTest] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('test', test);
  }, [test]);

   const redirectToNewPage = () => {
    props.history.push('/employee');
  };

return (
//Return something
)
}
```

When I redirect back to HooksMain from Employee page useEffect gets fired again. In my original code, it triggers web service call which I don't want. It keeps on making extra service call.

Request help!

Comment: set up a small demo of your case, and it will be easier to give you an answer.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-sea-krlff

Comment: If you change routes, you are un-mounting and re-mounting the component, so `test` will be changed (by being initialised in this instance of the component) each time. What is the service call you are trying to avoid? Could you perhaps pass in a prop to tell the component whether to fire the call on `test` change?

Comment: this works, if I pass information in props.history.push and check in main. But, grid becomes empty. All data gets lost somewhere. This never used to happen in class based components. Am I missing anything here?